# How to get details of file in internet?

Tags: c#, javascript, unityscript

i want get details of file(or movie,pic,...) in the internet before download is starting.
for example : IDM shown the details of file before download is starting.

Comment: To be appropriate for this site, you should list some things you've tried, or at least researched.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more in your question what your problem exactly is and what exactly are you trying to do. Ideally paste some minimal code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: How to get information about a file before you download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's really no good way to do this that I know of. You can *sometimes* (depending on the setup of the server and whether it provides this) get the last modified date, which can be useful, but as far as actual metadata from the file, you'd have to either look into APIs that the server has (for example, I suspect there's a way via a separate call on the YouTube API to retrieve the length of a video without downloading it), or, more likely, download the file. Depending on the format, you might be lucky enough to be able to get away with only downloading some of it. But that's pretty unlikely too, I'd say.

It'd be a nice feature, but HTTP is just too general for most implementations to offer much useful information about specific file types.

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question, particularly if you add more detail to it. But the gist I get of what you're asking leads me to think it just isn't innately possible.